Factory Boy instance with start date before end date using SelfAttribute and Faker
Similar to this question about Laravel I'm hoping to create a FactoryBoy instance with start date before end date like this:


from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date

import factory


@dataclass
class DateRange:
    start: date
    end: date


class DateRangeFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = DateRange

    start = factory.Faker("date")
    end = factory.Faker("date_between_dates", date_start=factory.SelfAttribute("..start"))


print(DateRangeFactory())

This gives a hard-to-understand error:
faker.providers.date_time.ParseError: Can't parse date string `1984-11-11`

It looks to me like 1984-11-11 should be a perfectly acceptable date. What am I doing wrong?

Interestingly, it seems like this used to work, as my example is the same as one given in this closed issue

This might be related to the fact that factory.Faker("date") returns a date string not a date object.
A simple workaround would be to use date_between with no parameters, which will give you a real date, set to something sensible (a date in the past, but less than 30 years ago.)
This can be used in the end date without relying on string parsing:
class DateRangeFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = dict

    start = factory.Faker("date_between")
    end = factory.Faker("date_between", start_date=factory.SelfAttribute("..start"))

